# background images on area tag

Tags: jquery, css

Does anyone has any decent idea of how to add background images to the area tag?
I cannot use divs with position absolute as they will fall out of place on different resolutions and the jquery css('backgroundImage', '') function does not seem to work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [W3 documentation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/area), the `area` element does not accept any `style` attribute.

You can be interested in the [MapHilight](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/) jQuery plugin however.

**EDIT:**

After looking further into this, thanks to [graphicdivine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/231995/graphicdivine), it emerged that `style` is a [Global Attribute](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Attributes/_Global), that is, it *should* be supported by all HTML elements.

However, most of vendor implementations of `area` element do not support the style attribute, as one can test and as confirmed in the [`area` documentation of Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area):

> [*for the `area` element*] The id, class, and **style** attributes have the same meaning as the core
>   attributes defined in the HTML 4 specification, **but only Netscape and
>   Microsoft define them**.

Comment: There's nothing in the W3 link that states that the `area` tag does not accept `style` attributes.  There is no mention of "style" anywhere on the page. There is, however, a link to the global attributes page, which suggests that `style` is acceptable on an `area`

Comment: `style` is a global attribute.  "Global attributes are attributes common to all HTML elements; they can be used on all elements, though the attributes may have no effect on some elements."  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes

Comment: @graphicdivine you should always refer to W3 standard documentation. Mozilla is a vendor, and although it has a very rich documentation, it is not authoritative. The standard says that you should not use the `style` attribute in the `area` tag.

Comment: @graphicdivine You are right, I must have missed the link about global attributes which suggest that it can be used. However, it seems that it has no effect on the area. I will update my answer. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Nothing here either to clarify this: http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/embedded-content-0.html#the-area-element  It genuinely seems like nothing more than a convention that `area`s cannot be styled.

Comment: How strange. I wonder if some vendor have misunderstood the W3 documentation the way I did. I've found also [in the `area` documentation of Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area), among the notes: "The id, class, and **style** attributes have the same meaning as the core attributes defined in the HTML 4 specification, but **only Netscape and Microsoft define them**."